# Post content, PHP help

Tags: php

I am having some difficulty displaying post data.
I am entering my PHP into a PHP element of my front end page builder.

All I want is the post title wrapped in an H4 tag followed by the post content.

When I enter this on its own it works; `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>`

And when I enter this on its own it also works: `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>`

But when I add both snippets into the same PHP container it gives me a 404 error on the frontend.

Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks

Comment: ¿Are you in a loop? ¿Can you show us the entire code?

Comment: `<?php the_title( '<h4>', '</h4>' ); the_content(); ?>` might work.